# How to change mx record in cent os web server without third parties cp

Tags: mx-record

I am using CentOS dedicated server with matrix control panel, which doesn't have facility to change MX record so that I can send my email to google apps mail.

Comment: Is the centOS dedicated server also the DNS server?

Comment: yes it is a dns server as well

Answer (score 2):

You can hand edit the DNS files to make this change. The main file should be `/etc/named.conf`. In that will be two lines to pay attention to.

```
 options {
        directory "/var/named";
```

This tells you where your DNS zone-file is based in. Then, under the zone directive of your domain should be a line like:

```
    file "domains/named.local"
```

That file will be located at "/var/named/domains/named.local". Your location will be different. Open that file.

You should see a line in there for your current MX record.

```
example.com.        IN      MX  10   mail.example.com.
```

That is what you change to point to GoogleApps. At that point you reload the DNS process. I don't know what the exact CentOS command for this is, but you can do much the same thing by issuing a SIGHUP to the `named` process.

```
ps ax |grep namd
 4357 ?        Ss    25:19 /usr/local/sbin/named

kill -HUP 4357
```

This forces a reload of the domain files.